# getting meta data from resultset object in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using some custom queries in rails.
code snippet looks like

```
@time_spent = TimeEntry.find(:all,
                             :joins => "INNER JOIN sometable ON x = y",
                             :select =>"id, subject, spent_on")
```

now to get values I am using

```
@time_spent[index][:spent_on]
@time_spent[index][:subject]
```

what I want is to use index numbers in place of symbols. So that at run time I don't need to know the fields in the select clause.

for e.g. i want to do some thing similar to this

```
@time_spent[index][1]
@time_spent[index][2]
```

or

If I could get metadata of resultset i can use that information

Comments please?

Comment: to get field names from result set, use attributes.keys method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When @time_spent is a collection of objects, this will get the attribute's value for the index specified for the first [0] item in that collection:

```
@time_spent[0].attributes.values[index]
```

So, for example, to get the 5th attribute's value for the 2nd object in the collection:

```
@time_spent[1].attributes.values[4]
```

Answer (score 0):

to get field names from result set, use `attributes.keys` method